# Webdriver.io: what's the difference between the capabilities and desiredCapabilities keywords?

Tags: webdriver-io, google-chrome-headless

I'm using Webdriver.io to run UI tests in a Node environment.
I'd like to run Headless Chrome and came up with the following working configuration:

```
{
  capabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
       args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu']
     }
  }],
  services           : ['selenium-standalone'],
  execArgv           : ['--inspect']
}
```

However, I can't figure out whether `capabilities` is deprecated or not; I'm wondering because all the examples I see reference `desiredCapabilities` instead.
If I use `desiredCapabilities` though, then Chrome runs normally, not in headless mode.

I feel like I'm missing something, but I don't know what. Is there a significant difference between the two, and is one going away?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run webdriverio through the test runner (using a wdio.conf.js file), it uses `capabilities`.

If you run it in standalone mode (e.g. `node myTest.js`), it uses `desiredCapabilities`